# Integration question - a particle is moving in a straight line

Tags: integration

[image]

Here, I am not sure about this question. Like it says finding the expression of displacement and velocity, but it says from 0s to 6s. in that case shouldn't we need to find a value? Like definite integration? lower limit 0 and upper limit 6?
I am confused.

thanks.

Comment: You have $x'' = t - 6$ and when $t = 0$, $x' = 0$ and also $x = 0$ (why?). So integrate $x''$ to find $x'$ (velocity) then apply one of the above conditions to get your integration constant. Take a similar approach when integrating $x'$ to get $x$. Once you have your results for $x$ and $x'$, just evaluate both at $t = 6$ for the second part of your problem.

Comment: so in that case, I got 0 for the constant. Is that right? may you check? Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, you are right provided the point O the question specifies is the origin (which I assume it is). If so, you will then find both the integration constant for the velocity _and_ for the displacement are _both_ equal to $0$. The expressions I got were

$$x' = \frac{t^{2}}{2} - 6t$$

and

$$x = \frac{t^{3}}{6} - 3t^{2}$$

Comment: We want "displacement of the particle from $O$". This implies that we are indeed using $O$ as the origin of coordinates for this question. (And I agree with the implications in the previous comments.)

Answer (score 0):

Remember, when we integrate, there will be a constant term. Notice further that the question asked for you to find velocity and displacement at $t$ seconds, which should naturally be a function of $t.$ We can proceed as follows:
$$v(t) = \int (t - 6) dt = \boxed{\frac{1}{2}t^{2} - 6t + C}.$$
If we wish to find the velocity at $t = 6,$ we have
$$v(6) = \left[\frac{1}{2}t^{2} - 6t\right]_{0}^{6} = \boxed{-18}.$$

For the displacement, simply integrate the velocity function to get
$$x(t) = \int (\frac{1}{2}t^{2} - 6t + C) dx = \boxed{\frac{1}{6}t^{3} - 3t^{2} + Ct + D}.$$

I leave you to evaluate this from $x = 0$ to $x = 6.$

Comment: Why did you take the integral of $(6-t)$ and not $(t-6)$ as given in the question?

Comment: Indeed it really should be $t-6$ (or a negative sign should be prefixed to the entire formula); also, the conditions of the problem statement determine a particular formula without arbitrary constants of integration. Applied to the formulas above, the conditions imply that $C=0$ and $D=0$.

Comment: Why does a statement have to made into a question? Well, I don't know either :)